# Spring SOAP message parameters logging

Tags: spring, logging, soap

I want to log my incoming/outgoing messages. At the moment, I am able to log the whole message, just added `org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent` this into my log4j2 properties file. This logs as follows:

```
[TRACE] TIMESTAMP received - Received response [full message, very long and hard to read]
```

I'd like to log messages as follows:

```
[TRACE] TIMESTAMP - GetMyLoggingRequest(name: Mike, phone: 5444393)
[TRACE] TIMESTAMP - GetMyLoggingResponse(surname: Apple, status:"good")
```

Here it just logged the request and response with parameters, they were sent/received. Much easier to read!

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an interceptor:

```
@Component
public class CustomEndpointInterceptor implements EndpointInterceptor {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CustomEndpointInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Endpoint Request Handling");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Endpoint Response Handling");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Endpoint Exception Handling");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Execute code after completion");
    }
}
```

Add it to your config with:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class SoapServerConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {

        // register global interceptor
        interceptors.add(new CustomEndpointInterceptor());
   }

    ...

}
```

Comment: It's perfect. Thank you very much!